# Best way to populate Django Formset fields with Data from API?

Tags: django, forms, api, formset

So, I'm a total newb to formsets in Django, but here is what I got.

My forms.py file:

```
  class someForm(forms.ModelForm):
      name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
      class Meta:
           model = someModel

   SomeFormSet = formset_factory(someForm, extra=3)
```

My views.py file:

```
   class SomeTemplate(TemplateView)
       template_name = 'index.html'

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(SomeTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

            thing_number = self.request.GET.getlist('thing_number')

            queryResult = Thing.objects.using('api').prefetch_related('person').filter(thing_id__in=thing_number)

       formset = SomeFormSet(initial=[
          {'name': queryResult.name,  #trying this doesn't work, I want to populate each form with the API info,
        ])

        context['queryResult'] = queryResult
        context['formset'] = formset

        return context
```

I can get all the data I need from our API. And I can make a form with fields. My issue is how to combine them together, where the data is populating into the formset.

I've looked at the Django docs and have tried this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset. Adding additional fields, but that didn't seem to make sense. And I also tried what is currently in my code above.

Is the best way to populate the form dynamically from an API to use the "initial" Formset feature? I want to get my data into the fields (it could be for potentially tens of forms at a time)...

Comment: I don't know why you're looking at docs about adding additional fields; that's not what you want to do here at all. And this has nothing to with an API, you are simply querying model objects from your database. So the documentation you need to be looking at is [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: thanks @DanielRoseman !

Comment: Hey @DanielRoseman - AttendanceFormSet = modelformset_factory(ModelName, fields=('name')). How do I populate the "name" dynamically. I've got this: formset = AttendanceFormSet() in views.

Comment: As those docs show, you should just pass your whole queryset to AttendanceFormSet.